# Convergence/Divergence of infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I'm trying to figure out if the following series converges or diverges. I have spent hours on it and can't figure it out. Tried to use the comparison test, Dirichlet, and Abel, but none of it worked. Any hints?

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos^2(n)}{\sqrt{n}}
$$

Comment: Hey can you show what you did for the Abel comparasin test?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT:**

Recall that $\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$.

Comment: Is using this and splitting the series into two helpful? Is the addition of a divergent and a convergent series also divergent?

Comment: @peroxisome7, Yes. That is a version of contrapositive statement of the fact that difference of two convergent series is again convergent.

Comment: @peroxisome Note that $$\sum_{n=1}^N  \frac{\cos^2(n)}{\sqrt n} =\frac12 \sum_{N=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt n}+\frac12 \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\cos(2n)}{\sqrt n}$$Now, Dirichelt's test shows that the second partial sum on the right-hand side converges.  If the partial sum on the left-hand side converged, then the first partial sum on the right-hand side would be the sum (difference) of two convergent partial sums and hence would also converge.  Inasmuch as the first partial sum on the right-hand side diverges, what can one conclude?

Answer (score 8):

Another approach is to observe that among $e^{in}, n=1,2,\dots, 7,$ at least one of these points lies in the arc $\{e^{it}: t\in (-\pi/4,\pi/4)\}.$ Thus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{7} \frac{\cos^2 n}{\sqrt n} \ge \frac{1}{ 2}\frac{1}{\sqrt 7}.$$

The same thing happens for $n=8,\dots,14.$ etc. So the series in question is at least

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ 2}\frac{1}{\sqrt {7m}} = \infty.$$

Note that this idea will work if $\cos^2 n$ is replaced by $|\cos n|^p$ for any $p>0$.

Comment: (+1) I remember having used this trick to solve a previous question on the site. Under its apparence of simplicity, it is indeed rather powerful.

Comment: @zhw.  Inasmuch as at least one of the points $1,2,\dots, 7$ lies in that arc, $\cos^2(n)\ge 1/2$ for such a point.  Then, $\sum_{n=1}^7 \frac{\cos^2(n)}{\sqrt n}\ge \frac1{2\sqrt 7}$, would it not?

Comment: @MarkViola Right you are. Now edited.